Uncaught runtime errors： Infinite redirect in navigation guard
I have a vue3 router defined with the following routes
export const routes: Array<RouteRecordRaw> = [
  {
    path: "/",
    name: "浏览题目",
    component: HomeView,
    meta: {
      access: "canAdmin",
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/noAuth",
    name: "无权限",
    component: NoAuthView,
    meta: {
      access: "canAdmin",
    },
  },

  {
    path: "/admin",
    name: "管理员可见",
    component: AdminView,
    meta: {
      access: "canAdmin",
    },
  },
  {
    path: "/about",
    name: "关于我的",
    // route level code-splitting
    // this generates a separate chunk (about.[hash].js) for this route
    // which is lazy-loaded when the route is visited.
    component: () =>
      import(/* webpackChunkName: "about" */ "../views/AboutView.vue"),
  },

To implement a simple permission management function, determine whether the user has access permission based on the routing information of the page accessed by the user. If so, it will jump to the original page, otherwise it will be intercepted.
<script setup lang="ts">
import BasicLayout from "@/layouts/BasicLayout.vue";
import { useRouter } from "vue-router";
import { useStore } from "vuex";

const router = useRouter();
const store = useStore();
router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
  if (to.meta?.access === "canAdmin") {
    if (store.state.user.loginUser?.role !== "admin") {
      next("/noAuth");
      return;
    }
  }
  next();
});
</script>

Why do I get an error when I click to jump to another page after refreshing?

BTW using Vuex in Vue 3 is not a good idea. See Pinia

When user on the /noAuth page, your code check:

to.meta.access === "canAdmin" (true)
store.state.user.loginUser.role !== "admin" (true)

So, you get infinity redirections from /noAuth to /noAuth
On the /noAuth page you don't need check, user must be redirects to /noAuth? It does not make sense

How to change it

You can check, if current path = /noAuth, then you don't call next("/noAuth"), you need call next(), without arguments
